# Debian VM boot up error - "recovering journal"

Tags: debian, boot, grub

There was as power outage while I was making a copy of my Debian's virtual disk in my Windows host. Now, when started, the system shows the message:

```
/dev/sda1: recovering journal    
/dev/sda1: clean, 247572/393216 files, 1424558/1572608 blocks
```

And stays in this terminal screen. I tried the solution I read in this post on [**AskUbuntu**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924170/error-on-ubuntu-boot-up-recovering-journal/924335?noredirect=1#comment1512824_924335), and in some others threads, but nothing has solved the issue so far. My attempt was to boot to the GRUB menu and recovery mode, and as root: `umount /dev/sda1` and then `fsck -f /`, which showed all the 5 passes and the message:

```
/dev/sda1: 247576/393216 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 1425073/1572608 blocks
```

But when rebooting the system, the same message "recovering journal" is shown and nothing else loads. I also tried reinstalling `gnome-core`, but `sudo apt-get install gnome-core` gives me lots and lots of `Failed to fetch` errors. What can I try to get the system to work as before?

Comment: How long have you waited?

Comment: Approximately one hour

Comment: Strange indeed. Have you tried to regenerate your initrd file?

Comment: No, I haven't, how would I do that?

Comment: https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/fixing-broken-initrd-image-linux/

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I've done everything as instructed, but the issue still occurs when turning the machine on. All my /home/ files are accessible via recovery mode.

Comment: I would assume it is beyond repair, salvage the home dir and reinstall it. There are no guarantees multiples errors are not present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of multiple inconsistencies in the disk image file due to the power failure are very high.

As the behaviour is not a good sign, I would not sink time trying to recover something with such a low change of success.

Recover what you can of /home, and create/reinstall the VM.

Comment: Yes, that seems the appropriate thing to do. I did exactly that, using the live CD for recovering the files. Thanks!